# Argparse: modify default values based on dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have defined a parser, let's say:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My Parser')
parser.add_argument("--Arg0", type=str, default="str")
parser.add_argument('--Arg1', type=int, default=0)
```

Now I have a dict containing the same arguments/keys:

```
parameters = {'Arg0': "NewStr", 'Arg1': 0}
```

I want to replace the default values in my parser by the ones in the dict. I tried to iterate through the dict keys and do `parser.set_default(key=parameters[key])` but it just adds the new argument `key` with the value `parameters[key]`

So, how can I modify the parser default value for `Arg0` and `Arg1` based on the information contained in the dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ArgumentParser.set_defaults` like this:

```
parser.set_defaults(**parameters)
```

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that if I used an key in my dict that is not an argument in my parser, then it automatically adds the key as a new argument, which I do not want as it's not safe. Is there a way to avoid it?